# URL not shows specific Host name after uploading ASP project on IIS

Tags: iis-7, domain, hosting, asp.net, ip-address

![I have uploaded my ASP project on IIS server with 808 port, and when I try to open webpage by IIS server' Domain name **(xx.xxxxxxxx.com)** at that time it shows domain name in URL, but when try to open the tab/page on new tab that time it shows IP address of the IIS server with port number **(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:808/name.aspx)**.

Also when I open this web site with IP Address and port number **(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:808)**, in URL, browser shows as per tab clicked **(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:808/name.aspx)**, but when I open with domain name **(xx.xxxxxxxx.com)** that time it not shows any page name after domain name.

Please suggest me which changes I need to do in either ASP project or IIS.
So, when we open a webpage by domain name **(xxx.xxxxx.com)**, it open and don't show IP Address and port number **(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:808/name.aspx)**, i.e it shows **(xx.xxxxx.com/name.aspx)** ]

[please check snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfXGg.png)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is port 80. You need to move it to port 80. No other way other than using it in a frame within another site on port 80 (URL hiding)

The browser does not know that your site is on port 808. With http:// he aumatically tries port 80 because this is the standard port. Same with https:// it automatically tries port 443, which is assigned to HTTPS.

If you want to use another port, you need to specify it in the URL (or hide it using a frame)